# Why does this static reference to my instance not update internal values?

Tags: java, static, gson, deserialization, this

I've got a relatively complex piece of code that uses Gson to serialize objects in order to save very specific values for them. Alongside that, there is a certain object which controls a pretty heavy part of the code, and it's accessed very often, so in order to reduce uneccessary list managements to find it (these config objects are stored in lists), I create a static reference to access it faster, however it doesn't seem to work with the object.

I've simplified the code down, and the relationship here baffles me. If I use the code below, `active` will not update in the static reference to `this`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{ \"active\": false }";
    final MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

    myObject.fromGson(gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myObject.setActive(!myObject.isActive());
    }
}

private static class MyObject {
    @Expose private boolean active;
    private static MyObject self;

    public MyObject() {
        this.active = false;
        self = this; // notice where this line is located
    }

    public static boolean active() {
        return self.isActive();
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;

        System.out.println("this: " + this.isActive());
        System.out.println("self: " + self.isActive());
    }

    public void fromGson(MyObject object) {
        this.setActive(object.isActive());
    }
}
```

When tested, this outputs:

```
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: false
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: false
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: false
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: false
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: false
this: false
self: false
```

Clearly, `self` is not changing, even though it should just be accessing `this.isActive()`. Now consider the following change:

```
public MyObject() {
    this.active = false;
}

public void fromGson(MyObject object) {
    self = this; // notice the new position
    this.setActive(object.isActive());
}
```

And suddenly, upon testing the program, I get:

```
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: true
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: true
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: true
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: true
this: false
self: false
this: true
self: true
this: false
self: false
```

What is going on? Why is initializing self after Gson is finished serializing changing everything? Is gson the fault here? As far as the code is concerned, I'm pointing to the same `this` reference, so what's going on? Even if the solution would be to just move it to `fromGson`, what about the cases where it has nothing to deserialize from (which can happen in my original code if configs don't exist), where it won't invoke `fromGson`?

Comment: You have two instances of `MyObject`, but only the last instance is been used by `self`, but you're trying to update the first instance your created ... hello to the wonderful world of `static`.  The solution here would be NOT to have `MyObject` maintain this relationship

Comment: You know, after reading your comment, I was just about to post a response, except I immediately realized where my error was. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, as @MadProgrammer mentions, My reference to static is forcefully changed thanks to Gson. Since Gson serializes the value, my reference of `self = this` is modified to the deserialized `MyObject` from `Gson#fromJson`.

In order to avoid this, I have added a null check (personally, I don't like this static relationship dynamic anyways, and will probably scrap it):

```
private static MyObject self = null;

public MyObject() {
    this.active = false;
    if (self == null) { // prevents Gson from messing with it later on
        self = this;
    }
}
```